# Change SSH password in Git

Tags: git, ssh

Let's say my SSH username is `mygituser` and my password is `mygitpass` The new password should be `mygitnewpass`. How do I change my SSH password in Git?

Comment: Git sometimes uses public/private key authentication. In that case, the password you have to type is the password to your private key and not the password to Git. Use ssh-keygen to change the password of your private key.

Comment: I dont know which protocol :S
I'm a new programmer, so all what I do is every day I have to add, commit and push to the server. I gave my password to my colleague, so just I want to change my password to dont let anyone push the data unless me.

Comment: Yeah, you should never give anyone your password that you aren't comfortable with being you.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/m14t/3056747#gistcomment-1372842

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had to log in using:

```
ssh my_user@
```

and write

```
passwd
```

so all you will do:

```
ssh mygituser@example.com

passwd

mygitpass

mygitnewpass

mygitnewpass
```

Comment: Note that this is an exact answer for SSH, but as @zoul said, a different remote access method would require a different set of commands.

Comment: Example for https on GitHub Enterprise would be to do a "git https://username@githubserver.domain.blah/organization/repo.git"

Answer (score 7):

I don’t think that Git itself has anything like access control, or users and passwords. These have to do with the “transport layer” that you access your Git remote through. Most often Git uses SSH as a transport layer, so that you’ve got to have an SSH account on the machine hosting the remote and if you want to change your “Git password”, you really want to change your SSH password on that box (or the passphrase of your private key, as Sjoerd points out). In other words, the answer depends on how you access the Git remote.

Comment: when I push the data to the server, I enter a password , this password has to be changed. is this called ssh password? (I'm a beginner :S ) Thank u

Comment: This is what we can't know without a crystal ball. Do you use the command-line client? What command do you use to push? What does `git remote show origin` say?

Comment: I use: "git push origin master"